# Regex search and replace SQL script

Tags: sql, regex

I have a bunch of SQL scripts that do this:

```
COALESCE([18], 0),COALESCE([19], 0),COALESCE([20], 0),COALESCE([21], 0) ect
```

Is there a way to use regex to update them to do this:

```
COALESCE([18], 0) as [18], COALESCE([19], 0) as [19], COALESCE([20], 0) as [20], COALESCE([21], 0) as [21]
```

Comment: Regex in what tool (e.g. SSMS or Notepad++) or on what platform (e.g. Windows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find:**

```
[^()]+\(\[(\d+)\][^)]+\)
```

**Replace:**

```
$0 AS [$1]
```

Demo:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/5Jb2iCcear0fbBwu)

Comment: I could not get this to work in SQL Server Management Studio. It did work perfectly with Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

```
(.*?(\[\d+\]).*?\))
```

This will work as well.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/wE4xX6/2